# Python: Showing percentage of operation

Tags: python

I'm doing some stuff on several lines of data. This takes a long time, and I would like to show the percentage of progress.

So I have the following code:

```
for y in range(0, height):
    if (y * 100 / height).is_integer():
        print("... ", int(y * 100 / height), "%")
```

`height` is the number of lines that need to be processed.

However, somehow this code doesn't print the correct percentages. If height is 100 it works fine. For 4050 it prints every 2 percentages (0%, 2%, 4%, ...). For 2025 it prints every 4 percentages...

Why does this happen? And how can I fix it?

Comment: [Why not use a ready-made library?](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm)

Comment: If you simulate the first few iterations in a repl you'll easily see why -- going from the `i`th iteration to the `i+1`th iteration might easily step from, say, 0.8% complete to 1.2% complete, neither of which are integers.

Comment: Hmm, that looks very nice. Still, would love to know the answer :P

Comment: @leaf +1 for introducing this lib :)

Comment: @Cameron Damn yes, that makes so much sense! So stupid I didn't realise this myself.

Comment: why not just using a counter divided by the total of lines? I didn't understand very well what you meant on this if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly proud of my code, but anyway:

```
last = -1 # Start it as -1, so that it still prints 0%.
for y in range(0, height):
    work = int(y * 100 / height) # I assigned the percentage to a variable for neatness.
    if work != last: # so it doesn't print the same percent over and over.
        print("... ", work, "%")
    last = work # Reset 'last'.
```

This may/may not be completely accurate. But it works

The reason you had your problem is from the is_integer() was only true on specific values.

Hope this helps!